# Which .SO Linux has RAM information

Tags: linux, .net-core, .so

I am trying to implement a .Net Core application which will check the amount of ram on different OS.

For Windows it was easy, as I used the kernel through DllImport.

But for Linux I cannot seem to find any info on which SO provides this information. I have off course found suggestions using bash commands.

Thanks in advance!
TheFreeman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont bother with `DllImport`. On Linux, you can just read the `/proc/meminfo` file. The format is described [here](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-meminfo.html).

I guess you want the these 3 lines:

```
MemTotal:       15849336 kB  
MemFree:        10555972 kB  
MemAvailable:   13025196 kB
```

Comment: Thanks will check it out :)